# Run tests for library project with different dependency sets

Tags: java, spring, gradle, junit, dependencies

Environment:

- Java 8
- Gradle 4
- JUnit 5

I have a library project that supports multiple setups / optional dependencies.

The library always requires Spring Boot + grpc-java.
However the user of the lib can decide whether he wants to use either netty or netty-shaded.
And finally the lib adds additional features if Spring-Security and/or Spring-Cloud are present.

I have a set of tests that runs with the default setup (netty + Spring-Security).
How do I test that I can also use all features from the library with the other setup combinations, without copying my tests multiple times?

(During the last update I used a class from the wrong lib in one of the library classes and thus the library didn't work correctly if the optional dependency was missing. Now I want to prevent similar issues in the future)

**Possible solutions**

- Create a test lib project that contains the test code and create multiple test projects that execute the tests from that lib.

Not all tests work for all setups. (A security test will obviously fail if no security lib is present).
Unfortunately the number of test projects can easily explode. Currently ~8 projects are needed to test all possible combinations. If I add another optional dependency (which I consider to do) this will increase to 16.
If there is nothing easier way, I probably use this one.

- Copy the dependencies to a specific folder and use some code to add them to the classloader dynamically.

This requires extra coding and some bad classloader magic and possibly a forked test execution mode, that does not execute the tests in parallel (because they might have to bind a port)

**TLDR:** Is there an easy way to run JUnit 5 Tests with different dependency sets using gradle?